# Shadcn - Type 'CheckedState' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ChangeEvent<Element>'

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, next.js, react-hook-form

I am encountering an error in my code that uses the shadcdn library. The error specifically occurs with the Checkbox onCheckedChange event in the following part of my code:

```
<FormField
    control={form.control}
    name="remember"
    render={({field}) => (
        <FormItem className="flex flex-row items-start space-x-3 space-y-0.5">
            <FormControl>
                <Checkbox checked={field.value} onCheckedChange={field.onChange}/>
            </FormControl>
            <div className="space-y-1 leading-none">
                <FormLabel className="text-md cursor-pointer select-none">Angemeldet bleiben</FormLabel>
            </div>
        </FormItem>
    )}
/>
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
TS2322: Type '(event: boolean | ChangeEvent<Element>) => void' is not assignable to type '(checked: CheckedState) => void'. Types of parameters 'event' and 'checked' are incompatible. Type 'CheckedState' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ChangeEvent<Element>'. Type '"indeterminate"' is not assignable to type 'boolean | ChangeEvent<Element>'.
```

Additionally, I am also using react-hook-form and zod for validation, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(authSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        email: "john.doe@example.com",
        password: "123456",
        remember: false
    }
});
```

Could you please help me understand the cause of this error and suggest a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Is seems to be a known [issue](https://%20%20https://github.com/shadcn/ui/issues/657#issuecomment-1603600363) with ReactHookForm. The current solution is to roll back to `react-hook-form@v7.44.3`

**Original answer**

I can't replicate your code, but the typescript error suggests that the `onCheckedChange` handler isn't compatible with the `field.onChange` event.
Firstly, try

```
onCheckedChange={event => field.onChange(event.target.checked)}
```

If that doesn't work because it thinks event could be a boolean, try:

```
onCheckedChange={event => {
    const isChecked = typeof event === "boolean" ? event : event.target.checked;
    field.onChange(isChecked);
}}
```

This may not be perfect as I can't see what CheckedState should be, but hopefully this will answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The first one gives me an error:
TS2339: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'CheckedState'.   Property 'target' does not exist on type 'false'.
Second: 
TS2339: Property 'target' does not exist on type '"indeterminate"'.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the outstanding issue. The original answer assumed that the `CheckedState` was true or false, but it appears it can be `'indeterminate'` as well. Rather than adjusting the answer to reflect the different states, I have just suggested the solution in the issues page. If you want me to suggest an alternative typing answer I can try.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Once downgraded to react-hook-form@v7.44.3, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same issue, a bad workaround will be to use !!

```
            <Checkbox
              checked={selectAll}
              onCheckedChange={(checked) => {

                booleanChecked = !!checked;

              }}
            >
```

it is bad because it is skirting the typescript error which is saying internally that checked can be inderminate also and that cannot be assigned to boolean. Which should be properly handled.